# Receiving ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas

In my attempt to display values in a `DataFrame`, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called

I am using a csv file. If I print `unique_users`, the value prints and it's an `int64` data type.  Does anyone know why that might be?

```
user_counts = df["SN"].value_counts()
unique_users = user_counts.count()

unq_usr = pd.DataFrame(unique_users)
unq_usr
```

Comment: please include your code that defines\constructs `pd` and field member `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
unq_usr = unique_users.reset_index()
```

Since the dataframe call from pandas does not take `int`